# Disable layout in Zend Framework 3?

Tags: zend-framework3

How to disable layout in Zend Framework 3?

Trying to get response from an Ajax call, it needs layout to be disabled.

Comment: You can send a JsonModel as response which will disable layout if your respond is json.

Comment: @MehmetSÖĞÜNMEZ how??

Comment: Return New JsonModel ([data]); you will need zend-json.  Checkout: https://olegkrivtsov.github.io/using-zend-framework-3-book/html/en/Model_View_Controller/View_Rendering_Strategies.html

Answer (score 8):

Here it is

```
public function indexAction(){
    $view = new \Zend\View\Model\ViewModel();
    $view->setTerminal(true);

    return $view;
}
```